# ManyToOne not mapped with the parent ID

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I am trying to implement tests in my spring boot app, but I have problems with ManyToOne/OneToMany links.

It seems that the link from the subobject is not created, while I use CascadeType = ALL.

I tried creating it in the BusinesDomain.addSubdomain, adding "subDomain.domain(this);" but this causes a loop.

I found out other topics with the same error but non of them seem to cover my issue.

Could you please help me find out what seems to be the issue ?

Thanks a lot!

Here are my Entities

```
import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.NonNull;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.experimental.Accessors;

@Accessors(fluent = true)
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
public class BusinessDomain {
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @NonNull
    @Column(unique=true)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "domain", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<BusinessSubDomain> subDomains = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    public void addSubDomain(BusinessSubDomain subDomain) {
        subDomains.add(subDomain);
    }
}

@Accessors(fluent = true)
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
public class BusinessSubDomain {
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "business_domain_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    private BusinessDomain domain;
}
```

My service class:

```
@Override
public BusinessDomain saveOrUpdate(BusinessDomain businessDomain) throws OrcaException {
    try {
        BusinessDomain domain = businessDomainRepository.findByName(businessDomain.name());
        if(null == domain) {
        // Repository class not overriden (extends CrudRepository<BusinessDomain, Long>)
            return businessDomainRepository.save(businessDomain);
        } else {
            domain.description(businessDomain.description());
            domain.subDomains(businessDomain.subDomains());
            return businessDomainRepository.save(domain);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new OrcaException(e);
    }
}
```

And my Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class BusinessDomainTest {
    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void createBusinessDomainWithSubDomain() throws OrcaException {
        BusinessDomain passengerBusinessDomain = new BusinessDomain().name(DOMAIN_NAME).description(DOMAIN_DESCRIPTION);
        BusinessSubDomain distributionBusinessSubDomain = new BusinessSubDomain().name(SUBDOMAIN_NAME)
                .description(SUBDOMAIN_DESCRIPTION);
        passengerBusinessDomain.addSubDomain(distributionBusinessSubDomain);
        businessDomainService.saveOrUpdate(passengerBusinessDomain);
        BusinessDomain domain = businessDomainService.findByName(DOMAIN_NAME);
    }
}
```

With this I get the error message:

> [main] INFO
>   com.myproject.project.test.model.soadatamodel.business.domaining.BusinessDomainTest
>   - Started BusinessDomainTest in 24.161 seconds (JVM running for 26.159) [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionContext -
>   Began transaction (1) for test context [DefaultTestContext@76480730
>   testClass = BusinessDomainTest, testInstance =
>   com.myproject.project.test.model.soadatamodel.business.domaining.BusinessDomainTest@405a296e,
>   testMethod = createBusinessDomainWithArea@BusinessDomainTest,
>   testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration =
>   [WebMergedContextConfiguration@5f5c2451 testClass =
>   BusinessDomainTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class
>   com.myproject.project.TestApplication}', contextInitializerClasses =
>   '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}',
>   propertySourceProperties =
>   '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}',
>   contextCustomizers =
>   set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextCustomizer@6eceb130,
>   org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@47db50c5,
>   org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0,
>   org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0,
>   org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@68ceda24],
>   resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader =
>   'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader',
>   parent = [null]]]; transaction manager
>   [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager@28d97205]; rollback
>   [true] [main] INFO
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator -
>   HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory Hibernate: select
>   businessdo0_.id as id1_1_, businessdo0_.description as descript2_1_,
>   businessdo0_.name as name3_1_ from BusinessDomain businessdo0_ where
>   businessdo0_.name=? Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
>   Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence [main] WARN
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 23502,
>   SQLState: 23502 [main] ERROR
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - NULL not allowed
>   for column "BUSINESS_DOMAIN_ID"; SQL statement: insert into
>   BusinessSubDomain (description, business_domain_id, name, id) values
>   (?, ?, ?, ?) [23502-168] [main] INFO
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl -
>   HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
>   org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not
>   execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
>   execute statement     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:278)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:488)
>     at
>   org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
>     at
>   org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
>     at
>   org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134.findByName(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.myproject.project.service.soadatamodel.business.domaining.impl.BusinessDomainServiceImpl.findByName(BusinessDomainServiceImpl.java:40)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy137.findByName(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.myproject.project.test.model.soadatamodel.business.domaining.BusinessDomainTest.createBusinessDomainWithArea(BusinessDomainTest.java:82)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)Hibernate:
>   call next value for hibernate_sequence Hibernate: insert into
>   BusinessDomain (description, name, id) values (?, ?, ?) Hibernate:
>   insert into BusinessSubDomain (description, business_domain_id, name,
>   id) values (?, ?, ?, ?) could not execute statement; SQL [n/a];
>   constraint [null]; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
>   execute statement
>   org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not
>   execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
>   execute statement
>
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
>     at
>   org.junit.rules.ExpectedException$ExpectedExceptionStatement.evaluate(ExpectedException.java:239)
>     at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could
>   not execute statement     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:112)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:207)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2949)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3449)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:582)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:456)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:50)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1251)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1319)   at
>   org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:87)  at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606)     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:529)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getSingleResult(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:54)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:206)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:85)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:116)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:106)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:483)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
>     ... 56 more Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: NULL not allowed
>   for column "BUSINESS_DOMAIN_ID"; SQL statement: insert into
>   BusinessSubDomain (description, business_domain_id, name, id) values
>   (?, ?, ?, ?) [23502-168]  at
>   org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
>     at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169)     at
>   org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:146)  at
>   org.h2.table.Column.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Column.java:293)    at
>   org.h2.table.Table.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Table.java:689)  at
>   org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:120)     at
>   org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:84)  at
>   org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:75)  at
>   org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:230)    at
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:156)
>     at
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:142)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy130.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
>     ... 84 more [main] INFO
>   org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionContext -
>   Rolled back transaction for test context [DefaultTestContext@76480730
>   testClass = BusinessDomainTest, testInstance =
>   com.myproject.project.test.model.soadatamodel.business.domaining.BusinessDomainTest@405a296e,
>   testMethod = createBusinessDomainWithArea@BusinessDomainTest,
>   testException = [ERROR CODE : UNKNWN001]  Unknown Error [Exception
>   :org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not
>   execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
>   execute statement], mergedContextConfiguration =
>   [WebMergedContextConfiguration@5f5c2451 testClass =
>   BusinessDomainTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class
>   com.myproject.project.TestApplication}', contextInitializerClasses =
>   '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}',
>   propertySourceProperties =
>   '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}',
>   contextCustomizers =
>   set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextCustomizer@6eceb130,
>   org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@47db50c5,
>   org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0,
>   org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0,
>   org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@68ceda24],
>   resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader =
>   'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader',
>   parent = [null]]]. [main] INFO
>   org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionContext -
>   Began transaction (1) for test context [DefaultTestContext@76480730
>   testClass = BusinessDomainTest, testInstance =
>   com.myproject.project.test.model.soadatamodel.business.domaining.BusinessDomainTest@685e8e17,
>   testMethod = createSimpleBusinessDomain@BusinessDomainTest,
>   testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration =
>   [WebMergedContextConfiguration@5f5c2451 testClass =
>   BusinessDomainTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class
>   com.myproject.project.TestApplication}', contextInitializerClasses =
>   '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}',
>   propertySourceProperties =
>   '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}',
>   contextCustomizers =
>   set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextCustomizer@6eceb130,
>   org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@47db50c5,
>   org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0,
>   org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0,
>   org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@68ceda24],
>   resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader =
>   'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader',
>   parent = [null]]]; transaction manager
>   [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager@28d97205]; rollback
>   [true]

Comment: going to set the "domain" on the subDomain? aka setting both sides of the relation

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.... please dont add that much content as not many users will be likely to help

Comment: Hello, I tried to set the domain on the subdomain but I got a infinite loop (cf my first post) :(

Answer (score 1):

Finally I understood.

First, the entity adder must be

```
public void addSubDomain(BusinessSubDomain subDomain) {
    subDomains.add(subDomain);
    subDomain.domain(this);
}
```

But this was causing an infinite loop with an infinite call to hash method.

I solved this (caused by lombok) using @Getter and @Setter instead of @Data in my entity.

Thanks